# Get all related many-to-many objects from a Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I have a twisty maze of interrelated Django models, with many-to-many fields describing the relationships.

What's the cleanest way to get a list of unique members of a related model from a QuerySet?

If I have a Item model with a groups ManyToMany pointing to the Groups model.

If I have a queryset of Items, of 'items', how do I get this:

```
groups = items[0].groups.all().values_list('name', flat=True)
```

But for the whole set?  Do I need to iterate through them all and do set().intersect() ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One solution is to use 2 queries.

You can use the reverse relationships to query all `Group`s that an `Item` in your `items` points to.

```
groups = groups.objects.filter(item__in=items).distinct().values_list('name', flat=True)
```

Comment: Sufficiently elegant.  Thanks.

Comment: You may also find it useful to use `flat=True` as a parameter to `values_list`, which will return the result as a list of names, rather than a list of tuples of names.

Comment: @gorus -- updated. I'm finding it funny I removed flat from the original post because I got it confused with distinct.